# How to convert to dollars and cents -- rounding, and with comma separators

Tags: emacs, elisp

The following code excerpt will add up a column of numbers and yield results that are several decimal points long.  Could anyone please give an example of how to convert the results into dollars and cents, rounding to the second decimal -- i.e., `1.555` should round *up* to `1.56`; and `1.554` should round *down* to `1.55`.  Also, I'd like to insert comma separators every three digits to the left of the decimal point -- e.g., `1124412.555` should be converted to `1,124,412.56`.

```
(let ((sum 0))
  (while (re-search-forward "[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+" nil t)
    (setq sum (+ sum (string-to-number (match-string 0)))))
  (insert "\n\nTotal Hours:  " (format "%s" sum ))
  (insert "\n\nTotal Fee for Services Rendered:  " (format "%s" (* 250 sum)))
  (insert "\n\nOne-third of total fee:  " (format "%s" (/ (* 250 sum) 3))))

2.0
0.2
0.1
4.75
4.0
6.5
0.1

Total Hours:  17.650000000000002

Total Fee for Services Rendered:  4412.500000000001

One-third of total fee:  1470.8333333333337
```

---

Based upon the answers provided by @Drew and @abo-abo, the following is a revised draft that now appears to be working correctly:

```
08884.75585
78774.1235
6.545

Total Hours:  87,665.42

Total Fee:  $21,916,356.09

One-Third:  $7,305,452.03

(let ((sum 0))
  (while (re-search-forward "[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+" nil t)
    (setq sum (+ sum (string-to-number (match-string 0)))))
    (setq total-hours (group-number (number-conversion (format "%s" sum ))))
    (setq services-rendered (group-number (number-conversion (format "%s" (* 250 sum)))))
    (setq one-third (group-number (number-conversion (format "%s" (/ (* 250 sum) 3)))))
  (insert "\n\nTotal Hours:  " total-hours)
  (insert "\n\nTotal Fee:  $" services-rendered)
  (insert "\n\nOne-Third:  $"  one-third) )

;; @abo-abo
(defun number-conversion (str)
  (let ((x (read str)))
    (format "%0.2f" (* 0.01 (round (* 100 x)))) ))

;; http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElispCookbook#toc23
(defun group-number (num &optional size char)
    "Format NUM as string grouped to SIZE with CHAR."
    ;; Based on code for `math-group-float' in calc-ext.el
    (let* ((size (or size 3))
           (char (or char ","))
           (str (if (stringp num)
                    num
                  (number-to-string num)))
           (pt (or (string-match "[^0-9a-zA-Z]" str) (length str))))
      (while (> pt size)
        (setq str (concat (substring str 0 (- pt size))
                          char
                          (substring str (- pt size)))
              pt (- pt size)))
      str))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe abo-abo's `(* 0.01 (round (* 100 x)))` can lead to surprises in corner cases (because 0.01 cannot be represented exactly in the internal floating point representation).  A simpler solution for the rounding is:

```
(format "%0.2f" x)
```

Comment: Yes, if it's necessary for the numbers to be *exact* (which may or may not be the case here, but frequently is when the numbers represent money), then you shouldn't use floating-point numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much -- I've updated my working draft in the question to reflect the code you provided.

Comment: My attempt to combine the function of @abo-abo with your code isn't working correctly.  Evaluating (number-conversion "4.37") yields a result of 4.38 -- the correct result should be 4.37.  It should only round up to 4.38 if it was 4.375, 4.376, 4.377, 4.378, or 4.379.  Any ideas on how to correct the function?  I'm using `(defun number-conversion (str) (let ((x (read str))) (format "%0.2f" (+ x 0.005)) ))`

Comment: Oh, indeed. `(format "%0.2f" x)` is the right solution, because %0.2f already rounds (rather than truncating).

Comment: `(stefan "1.555")` does not seem to be rounding up using `(defun stefan (str) (let ((x (read str))) (format "%0.2f" x) ))`

Comment: Could simply be due to a rounding error when "read"ing.  After all, 1.555 cannot be represented exactly in the internal floating point representation.  Or maybe it's because the rounding from a middle point like 1.555 is done down rather than up (there are many different ways to do rounding for those middle points: to zero, to plus-infinity, to minus-infinitiy, away from zero, to even, ...).

Answer (score 2):

Use `(format "%.2f" YOUR-NUMBER)`.  For example:

```
(insert "\n\nOne-third of total fee:  " (format "%.2f" (/ (* 250 sum) 3))))
```

The `f` says to use decimal-point notation. The `.2` says to show two decimal places.  See the doc string of `format` or the Elisp manual, node `Formatting Strings`.

As far as I know, in Emacs Lisp there is no predefined format specifier that gives you comma-separated digit grouping.  In Common Lisp `format` is much more powerful (a language by itself).

If you really need comma separation then you will need to write code that parses the text (e.g. the string returned from `format`) and insert commas where needed.  Perhaps someone else will bother to do that for you here, but you can probably do it yourself, given the info you have so far.  There is nothing predefined that will help magically with this.

But [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElispCookbook#toc23) might help with the commas.

Comment: Mission accomplished -- thank you very much.  I've updated the question with a working draft that appears to resolve everything -- it uses your suggestion of `group-number` from the `EmacsWiki: Elisp Cookbook`, and the `num->dollars` function provided by @abo-abo (which I renamed to `number-conversion`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code:

```
(defun num->dollars (str)
  (let ((x (read str)))
    (replace-regexp-in-string
     "\\."
     ","
     (format "%0.2f"
             (* 0.01 (round (* 100 x)))))))

(mapcar
 #'num->dollars
 '("4412.500000000001" "1470.8333333333337" "1.555" "1.554"))

 ; => ("4412,50" "1470,83" "1,56" "1,55")
```

Comment: I think the commas he wants are for grouping. E.g., `1,234.56` instead of `1234.56`, and not `1234,56`. IOW, not using a comma as the decimal point, but for grouping: thousands, millions,...

Comment: It looks like the answer is a combination of abo-abo (who resolved the rounding issue), and @Drew (who resolved the comma issue with a citation to `group-number` in the EmacsWiki: Elisp Cookbook).  I'll consolidate the functions and report back.  Thank you both very much.

Comment: Somehow, I didn't notice that you were asking about rounding also. I thought you had the number and were asking only about formatting the numeral.

Comment: Know it is a old list and lots of comment using "format "%... which my sbcl reject as format t/stream/... not a string there!  But examples kept on coming. I even copy this code and it does not work.  is there some switch or something I miss.  So not Lisp!

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's worth considering the built-in `calc` library when dealing with money values (or other decimal fractions where precision is critical).

`calc` uses a decimal representation for floating-point numbers (rather than binary), so is not subject to the classical float rounding issues when dealing with decimal values.

It can also take care of grouping digits for display.

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(calc)` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for the reference to `calc` -- greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's a real wealth of features in `calc`, and while it's also consequently complex, there's one *very* simple and convenient interface in the form of `calc-eval` (but take careful note that you use infix notation with this function, not prefix).